# Google Recaptcha throwing errors on reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, captcha, recaptcha

I am trying to get Google Recaptcha to work on one of my sites but I am facing some problems. I am following the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) and using the explicit render function to create the recaptcha widget.

The form that contains the captcha can be reused without reloading the page. In other words, when someone successfully submits the form for the first time, it collapses and a button is shown that allows users to use the form again.

When this button is clicked I call the reset function in JS to make the captcha work again. The details of this function can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api). When the reset function is called, this error appears in the console;

**Error: Permission denied to access property '10_1417377045946'**

After that when someone tries to use the captcha the following error pops up:

**The page at http:// google.com says:** An error occurred while contacting the recaptcha service.

Can someone please help me find a solution to this issue? Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, could you fix it?

Comment: No I was unable to fix it. Let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: I also could not fix that issue. Changed to another implementation.

Comment: Which one are you using now?

Comment: I am using this one now: http://www.99points.info/2010/08/ajax-stylish-captcha-and-contact-form-using-jquery-and-php/

Comment: Google has an open issue on this on Github https://github.com/Kelimion/recaptcha/issues/220 (Seems to occur in IE only?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came accross the same error while implementing this on my own website.
This is the workaround I use :

I have added an id to the div holding the re-captcha, like this :

```
<div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_key"></div>
```

And when I need to reload the re-captcha, I use this piece of javascript:

```
        var recaptchaframe = $('#recaptcha iframe');
        var recaptchaSoure = recaptchaframe[0].src;
        recaptchaframe[0].src = '';
        setInterval(function () { recaptchaframe[0].src = recaptchaSoure; }, 500);
```

First I tried to set the src directly to itself again, but that did not refresh the iframe. Then I tried to set it to nothing and directly back to the source without using the interval, but that also did not refresh the frame.

Finally in combination with the interval it refreshes nicely and I don't get the Access Denied error that I got with the reset command.

Answer (score 1):

If You need to reset / reload Google reCAPTCHA just use `grecaptcha.reset();`

(This doesn't throw any errors.)

Answer (score -1):

THX Huron!

Is a joke, that google makes a buggy thing like, and you can use the build in reset() method.

Also they dont write any line that says that the widget only can handle one request, so AJAX users heads up, use reset()!

But dont use reset()! Use @huron 's code.

By the way @huron 's code only works for one widget only, here is it for multiple:

```
var $recaptcha = $('.g-recaptcha iframe');
if ($recaptcha.length) {
    $recaptcha.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            recaptchaSoure = $this[0].src;

        $this[0].src = '';
        setInterval(function () { $this[0].src = recaptchaSoure; }, 500);
    });
}
```